# How is $W = \frac{1}{2}(W+W^T)$ although $W$ is not necessarily symmetric?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, toeplitz-matrices

I am currently studying [Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning by David Barber](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.Online), the 4th chapter exercise 4.3 (p 79). The exercise is the following:

> Show that for the Boltzmann machine defined on binary variables $x_i$ with $$p(\mathbf{x})= \frac{1}{Z(\mathbf{W},\mathbf{b})}\exp(\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b})$$
> one may assume, without loss of generality, $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{W}^T$

Here's the solution from the solution manual manual:

> The only place $\mathbf{W}$ eneters is through the expression $\phi \equiv \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$. Since this is a scalar, we can take the transpose, so that $\phi\equiv \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x}$ and $\phi = \mathbf{x}^T\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{W}^T)\mathbf{x}$. Hence any non-symmetric $\mathbf{W}$ is essentially converted to a symmetric form, so that we may therefore assume this symmetry with loss of generality.

I don't completely understand the solution. I have a couple of questions:

1. Couldn't the solution just say that since $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$ is a scalar, then the transpose of a scalar is the same scalar and hence we can write $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$ as $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x}$, and we are done. Why would they continue?
2. I know about the [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition_into_symmetric_and_skew-symmetric) decomposition where any square matrix can be represented as $X = \frac{1}{2}(X+X^T) + \frac{1}{2}(X-X^T)$, where the first summand is a symmetric matrix. But I don't understand why the solution writes out $W$ only in terms of the symmetric matrix. I went through 1 calculation and verified that it's true, but I still don't understand why we can write it only in terms of the first (symmetric) matrix. Am I missing something about $W$? Is it supposed to be symmetric?

Comment: The claim is not that $2W=W+W^T$ but that quantities of the form $2x^TWx=x^T(W+W^T)x$ can be understood from their value of $W+W^T$ only.

Comment: $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}= \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x}$ being true does not imply $\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{W}^T$, but does imply there is a symmetric matrix $\frac12(\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{W}^T)$ such that $\mathbf{x}^T\frac12(\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{W}^T)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean exactly by "can be understood"? Can you give an example of how it "can be understood"?

Comment: @Henry is that actually a theorem ?

Comment: It hardly amounts to a theorem: it is what your second quote says.

Comment: @Henry has stated a theorem; that theorem is what I was talking about in my comment.

Comment: Alternatively $x^T W x = \sum_{ij} x_i x_j W_{ij}$. $ x_i x_j$ is symmetric under exchanging $i$ with $j$, so only the symmetric part of $W$ remains.